# Как получить доступ к модели через в Django через скрипт

Tags: python, django

В приложении создал независимый скрипт, который подключаю в urls.py при запуске сервера.
Мне нужно получить доступ к бд через этот файл, но при импорта модели `from .models import Model`, django выдаёт ошибку `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`. Подключал в INSTALLED_APPS, но ошибка не пропала.

Comment: Покажите стектрейс. Вероятно, вы делаете запрос в БД в момент загрузки приложений, а так нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло впихнуть в начало кода:

```
import django
django.setup()
```